# Cannot insert information in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, permissions

I am trying to insert information locally in a database with I program that is codified in Java but I am not being able to. My guess is that it is somehow related to user permissions, even though I do not know what I should do aside from what I already have. My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS. My actions have been as follows:

I open a Command Line Interface window and get in MySQL via

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then I type in the password for root and get inside.

I set as data the database that has to be used with

```
use_data;
```

I create a new user with

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw';
```

I give the user all the required privileges to write information, regardless of the IP that would be used:

```
GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'user'@'linux' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `data` . * TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `data` . * TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `data` . * TO 'user'@'linux' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Yet when I try to access the database to insert information I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong not to obtain connection between my Java code and the database? The part of the code where the exception is being thrown is in the method getConnection, when I try to access the database.

```
@Override
    public void openDBConnection() throws Exception {
        //this method establish a database connection
        try {
            // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
            Class.forName(driver);

            String connection = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + dbname + "?"
                    + "user=" + user + "&password=" + passwd + "&useSSL=false"; 
            System.out.println(connection);

            // Setup the connection with the DB
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + dbname + "?"
                    + "user=" + user + "&password=" + passwd + "&useSSL=false");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the Java VM arguments you are using when launching your application ?

Comment: What is the value of `driver`? Which version of the MySQL Connector/J driver are you using, what is your Java version?

Comment: The driver is "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should try to check de *driver* value (for line `Class.forName(driver)`), and be sure that you are accessing to the right class.

Also, the error says *You do not have enough memory in your stack*, so you may change the *JVM Stack Size* to increase this (you can do this with `-Xss4m` jvm argument)

Comment: Under normal conditions a stack of 4 MB is a bit extreme, and shouldn't be necessary to do the classloading

Comment: The driver is "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". I am aware of the underlying significance of the error, but I am sure it happens as a result of trying to access the same result several times (hence the repeated traces), rather because the code is too demanding. Also, I have executed an example (vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html) and it was sucessful, with no JDBC or MySQL issues.

Comment: In any case, I have tried it and after adding it to Eclipse the same error happens.